# How to install pyqt4 on windows7 32 bits using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows7 32 bits. When I run a script, it complains

```
ImportError: No Module named 'PyQt4'
```

So I tried to install it, but pip install PyQt4 gives
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyQt4 although it does show up when I run

`pip search PyQt4`.

I tried to

`pip install python-qt`

which installed successfully but that didn't solve the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without knowing everything of your environment configuration (virtual or not, etc.).
But you may want to use Christoph Gohlke's excellent site (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and download this: PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl.

Was a lifesaver for me many times …

```
pip install pathToDownload\PyQt4‑4.11.4‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl
```